# Show an information based on shipping method chossen

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

[image: Woocommerce Cart Page]

When select the shipping method (UK Next Day) by the user, I want to show an information like "Select next day delivery and order before 2pm to receive your order on Wednesday 3 December 2014" below the order total.
Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

A link to you site page would have been helpful.
Assuming you are a developer i am giving you a solution on this issue, use this code to add a script to the page

```
function wdm_my_custom_function() {

}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_total', 'wdm_my_custom_function');
```

within the function you have to write the code which is in this link. As you can see it adds a dropdown in your case you have to change delete the dropdown from code and use the value of **UK NEXT DAY $$** in the script.

https://jsfiddle.net/jno9wzw4/

Let me know it it works for you.